# MySQL UPDATE WHERE behaves differently that SELECT WHERE

Tags: php, mysql

I have an $id = "4bd4e441-4866-097f-8b59-5b33a72029b5" in the database. When I do a SELECT it works:

```
 $sql = "SELECT *   FROM Open_Cases WHERE id = $id";
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($id));
```

However, when I try an UPDATE it does not work:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE Open_Cases set status = '2' 
        WHERE   id = $id";          
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($id));
```

I get an error that reads:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4bd4e441' in 'where clause'' in ...
```

If the value of $id = numerical, then both the SELECT and the UPDATE work the same. However, when the value of $id is alphanumerical, it fails.

Comment: `$id` contains string and it should be quoted `'$id'` in query

Comment: try this query : "UPDATE Open_Cases SET (status = '2') WHERE id = '$id'";

Comment: I already tried that and got the same error. It seems like it has something to do with the fact that the id has hyphens in the value. But it works for SELECT. When the id has numeric with no hyphens, the UPDATE works

Comment: Then i suggest you to move forward with [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), Donot inject values directly in query use placeholders

Comment: @VamMeej Is it possible that the SELECT was using an ID with no alphabetical characters, allowing it to be interpreted as a mathematical expression?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: The hyphen is a reserved character for update, this was done on purpose to prevent the column name to be interpreted as an expression. Select always interperates the column object as a string. What you do is store the hyphen as an underscore in the table. If it is viewable by a user, you replace the underscore with a hyphen. This should be like that in all sql modes including ASCII_MODE btw...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am using $q = $pdo->prepare($sql); It appears to be a case where I can only compare numerical ID but if the ID is alphanumerical it cannot find. I replaced the hyphens with "x" in the database, but it still does not work. id is the primary key.

Comment: The primary key must be a unique VALUE, that contains no NULL characters. Only integers (numbers) can be use as the primary key entries.

Comment: what I would do is just have an auto-increment for the table's primary key, but label it as IDX, then have your id column as a varchar field with a UNIQUE key attribute

Comment: @drtechno - that is a GREAT idea. Thank you so much!